# Android Two Grids with full height

Tags: android, gridview

Here is my xml for my view. I am trying to make the whole view scroll together. I have extended to grid to calculate the height  onmeasure and resize it but it is extremely slow.  Any other advise for me on how to achieve this?

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/msty_grey"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="2">

<!-- friends -->

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/activity_contacts_textview_friends"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    style="msty.contact.text.heading"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:text="MSTY FRIENDS" />

<GridView
    android:id="@+id/activity_contacts_gridview_friends"
    android:layout_below="@id/activity_contacts_textview_friends"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
    android:longClickable="false" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/activity_contacts_textview_other"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    style="msty.contact.text.heading"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:text="OTHER FRIENDS" />

<GridView
    android:id="@+id/activity_contacts_gridview_other"
    android:layout_below="@id/activity_contacts_textview_other"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit" />

<!-- other -->
```

Comment: Im not 100% sure what you are asking, but have you tried enclosing your root LinearLayout with a ScrollView?

Comment: I have yes. But the grids  don't extend/wrap to full hide. Then I extended the grid  to expand to 100% height but it is extremely slow.